# php files serving blank pages except for the login page on nginx

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I have a project that has the root directory ed_v001 and all the includes and settings are in a directory ed_v001/includes.

When i open it in a browser it displays the login page properly but when you login , the landing page will give an error 200
below is my default config file:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
    root /var/www/dc_v001;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name 192.xx.xx.xx;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /login.php;

        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root/login.php;
                #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root/index.php;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
 }
}
```

Comment: Tried adding another location that points out to the includes file but its still not working.The database configurations that are in the includes folder are working well.

Comment: So what is in logs? At least, consult the web server error log.

Comment: there is no errors in the error log file

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. The issue could be with the app. You might want to debug the PHP app.